# What does this pstops command do?

Tags: ps

I have a classical a4 format article written in tex, without any problems. ("Without any problems" meaning that would I do a `ps2pdf` I would get a `pdf` file I am totally ok with.)

After `latex` and `dvips` I get a ps file `file.ps` and I execute the following commands :

```
psbook file.ps temp1.ps
psnup -2 temp1.ps temp2.ps 
pstops.exe 2:0@1,1@1U(21cm,29.7cm) temp2.ps file.booklet.ps
ps2pdf file.booklet.ps file_booklet.pdf
```

The `psbook` command is supposed to rearrange the pages of `file.ps` in the proper order (I don't really get what it is supposed to mean here but anyway). The `psnup` command reduces its size: the area is divided by 2 by dividing its both dimensions by the square root of 2.

Then comes the `pstops` command. Reading the `pstops` man pages did not help me at all to understand what the command

```
pstops.exe 2:0@1,1@1U(21cm,29.7cm) temp2.ps file.booklet.ps
```

does but looking at the result (after the `ps2pdf` command) showed me what it is supposed to do : it rearranges the pages of `file.ps` from a4 to a5 and puts two a5 pages in an a4 landscape page so that after printing and folding the landscape a4 pages, we have a ready to write book(let) with pages in order.

I would like to precisely understand what the command

```
pstops.exe 2:0@1,1@1U(21cm,29.7cm) temp2.ps file.booklet.ps
```

does because its result is a bit flawed : there is sort of too much spaces between the two a5 pages when they are put side by side on the a4 landscape page so that the right one has approximatively 1cm of its right side missing. (Though I a am not sure that this flaw is only cause by the `pstops` command, because I think it could also be caused by the `psnup` command.) I tried to toy with the dimension `(21cm,29.7cm)` dimensions without success.

Would I be able to understand what the

```
pstops.exe 2:0@1,1@1U(21cm,29.7cm) temp2.ps file.booklet.ps
```

command does, I could modify and test and resolve my problem.

Comment: aren't psbook, psnup and pstops all doing the same thing here, just making n-up signature, do you really need all three?

Comment: I am really not at all a specialist of `psutils` but I think you need all three, as in all examples I came across, three where needed. Sadly all these examples didn't give me a clue about my particular `pstops` command.

Comment: the man page is imho quite clear (if one ignore the fact, that there is typo and "R, R, R" should read "R,U,H"). You place  two pages on one paper, the first unchanged, the second rotated and shifted.

Comment: So you're implying that my issue (the second page having a 1cm large band missing on its right, because being out of the a4 page) is not caused by `ps2ps` but by `psnup` ?